# Check effect of hook_schema_alter() hook

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to alter the comment subject field title width.

Core comment module sets it to 64 characters, and I want to change it up to 100 characters.

Now I tried to alter the schema using [hook_schema_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7) function. Below is my code snippet, which I tried,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_schema_alter().
 */
function comment_alter_schema_alter(&$schema) {
    if (isset($schema['comment'])) {
        $schema['comment']['fields']['subject'] = array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 100,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
        'description' => 'The comment title.',
        );
    }
}
```

I am confused whether do I have to write some stuff in `.install` file or not?

Now after installing module how can i check whether the width of subject field is increased or not. If I see the `comment` table then it is as it is to 64 characters. I could find this in your table structure using PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hook is not used to edit the database as such. It is used to alter the schema when using the [drupal_get_schema](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_schema/7)

> Gets the schema definition of a table, or the whole database schema.
>
> The returned schema will include any modifications made by any module
>   that implements hook_schema_alter().

To do what you want you will have to use the [db_change_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_change_field/7) and this would go in the .install file.

You can check out the [Schema API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7) to get other relavent functions

You have to write [db_change_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_change_field/7) in [hook_enable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7) function.

Here is my modified answer:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_enable().
 */
function comment_alter_enable() {
    db_change_field('comment', 'subject', 'subject', array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 100,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
        'description' => 'The comment title.',
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I have added following code in .install file, but it is still not working.     /**
     * Implements hook_install().
     */
    function comment_alter_install() {
     db_change_field('comment', 'subject', 'subject', array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 100,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
        'description' => 'The comment title.',
      )
     );
    }

Comment: did you uninstall and then reinstall the module>

Comment: yes. i did all the things..

Comment: can you try it in hook_enable.

Comment: you suggestion for hook_enable() worked...Cheers..Update the answer..

Comment: good it worked. But it should work in the hook install as well. Dont know why it did not :-) Could be because the module is already installed. It only calls it once when you enable the module for the first time. Disabling and enabling again will not call the function.

Comment: I tried to verify it, but couldn't due to time limit..will post you here as i find something interesting